# python sockets on Mac OS X gives AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'IF_INET'

Tags: python, macos, sockets, udp, homebrew

I am trying out some python network programming on Mac OS X 10.6. I am using Python 2.7 as installed by Homebrew, and am attempting to run a simple script from [Foundations Of Python Network Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590593715) (great book btw) that contains a UDP client and server, but am getting the aforementioned AttribuiteError when trying to use varibles from the socket module. The script is as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import socket, sys

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

MAX = 65535
PORT = 1060

if sys.argv[1:] == ['server']:
    s.bind(('127.0.0.1', PORT))
    print('Listening at', s.getsockname())
    while True:
        data, address = s.recvfrom(MAX)
        print('The client at ', address, ' says ', repr(data))
        s.sendto('Your data was %d bytes' % len(data), address)

elif sys.argv[1:] == ['client']:
    print('address before sending: ', s.getsockname())
    s.sendto('This is my message', ('127.0.0.1', PORT))
    print('address after sending: ', s.getsockname())
    data, address = s.recvfrom(MAX)
    print('The server at ', address, ' says ', repr(data))
else:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'usage: udp_local.py client|server'
```

Running this script via `python script.py server` results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "udp_local.py", line 5, in <module>
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AF_INET'
```

I have experimented with the python console, and after running `import socket` I can't seem to get any module variables. I have googled extensively and have yet to turn anything up with this same problem. Does anyone have any insight into what it might be? Just in case, here is the output of `env python`:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 10 2011, 10:39:45) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
```

Comment: Perhaps this is a problem with Homebrew?

Comment: Maybe, but when I try it with /usr/bin/python I get a similar problem. Regardless, I think I will try reinstalling the Homebrew python to see if that helps.

Comment: That's odd. What does `dir(socket)` show after import?

Comment: I had named my file as `socket.py`. There was another `socket.pyc` file in my working dir which was created when I ran it before. Removing it solved the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took a look at the Python source. On some platforms, `AF_INET` is defined in `SOCKET.py` or `IN.py`, which is automatically generated from `/usr/include/sys/socket.h` or something similar.

I couldn't actually see where this was defined for OSX, but it's possible something weird is going on in your version.

By far the most likely problem is that you've broken an important rule -- don't ever name a file after a module in the standard library. A `socket.py` file in your path or in the same directory as `udp_local.py` would cause errors like this. I recently did this with `argparse` while trying to answer a question here.

As a temporary workaround, you could try `AF_INET = 2` and `AF_INET = 1` -- it seems to be `2` in most places but may be `1` on non Unix platforms.

Comment: It very likely is a file name conflict as you suggest (especially if it fails with `/usr/bin/python2.6`) or possibly a file permission problem with the python library (can you `import _socket').  Whatever the case, this should work just fine on OS X.

Comment: And rather than building it yourself, you could try using a python.org installer for 2.7.2 (use the 64-bit/32-bit one here: http://www.python.org/download/

Comment: It was something related to that. I had a 'socket.py' file in the folder I was working in which was conflicting. I deleted the 'socket.py' file, but 'socket.pyc' was left hanging around. Deleting the .pyc file fixed it. The weird thing is, this still happened even if I was in a different folder and just running the python command prompt - ie socket.pyc is in ~/test and I was running python from ~/. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: It would happen if the Python script you were running was in ~/test, or if ~/test was in Python's search path.